# What flipped the general court in New Hampshire in 2018 from Republican to Democrat?

Tags: united-states, parties, state-legislatures

In 2018 Democrats took control of the [New Hampshire General Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Hampshire_General_Court) (the state legislature) in a big shift. Previously the Republicans had controlled the Court with a 14-10 majority in the Senate and a 216-176 majority in the House. But then in November 2018 Democrats won control by winning a 14-10 majority in the Senate and a 233-167. So, it was a big change.

What are the reasons put forward to explain this big change in balance of power?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a reason to think there are different reasons here than from the rest of the country where Democrats saw significant gains at the state and local level?

Comment: Unless this question becomes more focused I'm voting to close it. As it's currently written it accepts any random punditry as "reasons put forward" (by whom?).

Comment: The contrast would be starker if the leading paragraph provided more background, *i.e.* it should tell readers for how long before 2018 the NH legislature had remained Republican.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're hoping to dredge up Trumpian conspiracy theories here (which he [advanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_New_Hampshire_Senate_election) wrt NH before), the simple explanation is the "first past the post system". The popular vote swing was not substantial (+4% more D votes) compared to 2016, but it did put the Democrats over the 50% "bar" on average, in 2018.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so basically from this, you are saying that in a lot of the districts the balance is pretty tight, so when a wave comes through it can flip a lot of seats.